# How does Chrome JS console do pre-evaluation?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, programming-languages, v8, interpreter

Chrome JS Console only pre-evaluates (displays a gray result before you hit enter on a line of JavaScript code) expressions that don't have side effects. How does Chrome tell? Side effects tested: changing closured(non-local) variables, altering objects pointed to by non-local variables (including accessing properties with `get()` attributes that have side effects), async code (`setTimeout`), `console.log`, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

V8 has massive lists denoting which internal operations ("bytecode handlers", "intrinsics", and "builtins") are considered side effect free for this feature's purposes. See [src/debug/debug-evaluate.cc](https://chromium.googlesource.com/v8/v8/+/refs/heads/master/src/debug/debug-evaluate.cc) for all the gory details.

(This distinction is in no way exposed to, or relevant for, regular JavaScript operation; it's purely for debugger features.)

Comment: Thanks for the pointer! This is exactly what I was looking for. I was confused at first about how does V8 walk the stack and check for SideEffectFree-ness of operations in each frame without actually building the stack, but after looking up what [Bytecode](https://medium.com/dailyjs/understanding-v8s-bytecode-317d46c94775) is, based on my limited (barely any) knowledge in V8 it looks like it's V8's js intermediate representation, and [this](https://chromium.googlesource.com/v8/v8/+/refs/heads/master/src/debug/debug-evaluate.cc#918) starts to make more sense.